# Getting name of file after compiling

Tags: python

I'm trying to get name of current .exe file. Now I'm using

```
os.path.basename(__file__)
```

but it only returns name of .py file from which it has been compiled. Is there any way to get name of exe?

Comment: Question: How are 'interpreting' the python file as an executable?

Comment: Hi kacpo1, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a bit confusing. Are you running your python code from a .exe file?

Comment: In order to properly answer the question, we need to know how this python program was compiled into an executable. Or did you mean the python interpreter's executable, which is running the `.py` file? (in which case, you can just do `which python` on Unix or `where python` on Windows in the command line to check)

Comment: Oh sorry. Of course I mean that i run compiled python script. To compile it I'm using pyinstaller

Comment: Pyinstaller create self-extracting .zip file which creates temporary folder, unpacks python and script and runs script - so script rather doesn't know what was original .exe file.

Comment: That's not what i wanted. I want to compile my python script with pyinstaller into one executable file. The problem is that when I run compiled file, "____file____" returns name of python script and not an executable.

Answer (score 1):

I used `os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])`